# NPoco StructureMap.MVC4 Constructor Injection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, structuremap, npoco

I have an MVC4 application using StructureMap.MVC4.  Here's a fragment of IoC.cs

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>{
x.Scan(scan =>{
    scan.TheCallingAssembly();
    scan.WithDefaultConventions();});

x.For<IDbContext>().Use<EfDbContext>().Ctor<string>("connectionStringName").Is("DefaultDb");
x.For<IDatabase>().Use<Database>().Ctor<string>("connectionStringName").Is("DefaultDb");

x.For<IActionInvoker>().Use<InjectingActionInvoker>();
x.SetAllProperties(c=>c.OfType<IDbContext>());
... ...
```

DbContext injection works fine, so does the setter injection for ActionFilters, as well as all Service:IService using default convention.  But I got the following error trying to inject IDatabase:

```
Could not find a constructor parameter or property for NPoco.Database, NPoco, Version=1.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null named connectionStringName Parameter name: name
```

If I change it to

```
x.For<IDatabase>().Use(new Database("DefaultDb"));
```

It works.  Any ideas why?  I wonder if by using New, it will end up a different instance of IDatabase, especially when mixing with the IDbContext instance.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems related to StructureMap can't decide the default constructor when there are multiples with similar constructor parameters.  In this case, it has

```
Database(string connectionStringName)
Database(string connectionStringName, string Provider)
....
```

Looks like this is slight better syntax?

```
x.For<IDatabase>().Use(() => new Database("DefaultDb"));
```

Comment: My IDbContext has one constructor with connectionStringName and one constructor with IDbConnection and that works fine.  Seems IDatabase has too many overloaded constructor.